# while executing Citrus integration tests through maven is it possible to pass environmental variables like citrus xml file name pattern

Tags: maven, testng, citrus-framework

I have Integrartion test class which execute xml test cases at particular folder I am excuting xml test cases like this

```
mvn integration-test -Dtest=test name
```

I want to pass citrus  xml file name pattern while executing the above maven command how can I pass it suppose citrus by default taking /**/*IT.xml or /**/*Test.xml i want to change the pattern names like *something.xml I want to achive this through maven command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the property in Maven failsafe plugin (or surefire if you are using this plugin):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <citrus.xml.file.name.pattern>**/*Foo.xml</citrus.xml.file.name.pattern>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
```

In case you want to set this parameter as Maven command line argument you need to also introduce a new project property:

```
<properties>
  <filename.pattern>**/*Foo.xml</filename-pattern>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <citrus.xml.file.name.pattern>${filename.pattern}</citrus.xml.file.name.pattern>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Now you can call

```
mvn integration-test -Dfilename.pattern=**/*Something.xml
```